# Error: $(...).dialog is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to close a dialog outside the `$(document).ready` function

I get this error when I try to close it:

> Error: TypeError: $(...).dialog is not a function

How can I use the modal when I am outside `$(document).ready` function?

Code:

```
    $(document).ready(function ($) {
        function InitializeDialog($element) {

            $element.dialog({
                autoOpen: false,
                modal: false,
                width: 500,
                height: 150,
                resizable: false,

                close: function () {
                    $(this).dialog('destroy');
                }
            });

            $(".ui-dialog").find(".ui-dialog-titlebar").css({
                'background-image': 'none',
                'background-color': 'white',
                'border': 'none'
            });

        }

function UpdateProperty(propertyId, propertyName) {

        $.ajax({
            url: '/Home/UpdatePropertyByAjax',
            type: 'PUT',
            data: { PropertyId: propertyId, PropertyName: propertyName },
            success: function (response) {
                console.log(response);



                if (response > 0) {
                    $("#mytable tr").has("input[type=hidden][value=" + propertyId + "]").find("td:eq(0)").html(propertyName);
                }

$("#EditForm").dialog("close"); // Error happens here, The error message is 
Uncaught TypeError: $(...).dialog is not a function

                else {
                    alert('Property not updated');
                }

            },

            error: function (msg) {
                console.log(msg.responseText);
                alert(msg.responseText);
            }
        });

    }

    }
</script>
```

Comment: Have you included both *jQuery* and *jQuery UI*? The `.dialog()` function is within *jQuery UI*

Comment: Yes i did .. it works well when i open or close the modal inside ready() function but it's not working when  i open or close the modal outside ready() function

Comment: If it's copy to your code `} </script>` must be `});</script>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move it outside the `ready` handler if you need to reuse it

```
function showModal() {
  //your code here
} 

$(document).ready(function() {
  showModal();
});

showModal(); //both should fire
```

Also ensure that `$('#EditForm')` is returning an element. You can't dialog an element that isn't fetched from the DOM

Answer (score 0):

Something wrong with your jQuery implementation. You can do the same with the following code:

```
window.ready(function(){

    });
```

Comment: it works well when i open or close the modal inside ready() function but it's not working when  i open or close the modal outside ready() function